# QSystemTrayIcon - showMessage() doesn't show message immediately

Tags: qt

This is the code,

```
void MainWindow::start() { //a slot that responds to a button press
    //...
    trayIcon->setVisible(true);
    trayIcon->showMessage(tr("Foo"),
                      tr("Foo fooo foooo fooooo foooooo baaaaar"),
                          QSystemTrayIcon::Information,
                          1000);
    //...
}
```

But I don't see the message immediately after the button is pressed - it shows up after several seconds; sometimes it even doesn't show up at all. First, I tried removing all other statements in the function. But it didn't work. I tried `QApplication::processEvents();` too, but in vain. I Googled but couldn't come up with any relevant solution. Does anyone know how to find out what's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What operating system do you use? According to the [`showMessage`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsystemtrayicon.html#setContextMenu) documentation:

> Note that display of messages are dependent on the system
>   configuration and user preferences, and that messages may not appear
>   at all. Hence, it should not be relied upon as the sole means for
>   providing critical information.

Under Linux it works as expected. You could try calling `qApp->processEvents()` after the `showMessage` call.

Comment: I'm on Windows 8.1 right now. I've read that part in the documentation. But surprisingly the other programs that show messages are showing messages without any problem. It's only my application that, I don't know why, doesn't show messages (immediately).

Comment: Well, can you tell me how I can find out the root of my problem? Merely checking the code again and again is not helping.

Comment: Try to create a minimal application with just a tray icon and a push button. Does the press of the button displays the message? If yes then probably something else in your code causes the problem.

Comment: Yeah, I did that. The other program worked. Another thing I noticed is that the message shows up nicely during debug runs. I checked, rechecked and rerechecked my code. There is nothing visibly wrong that can cause that problem. Anyway, thanks for trying to help! :)